# grouping and aggregates with subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a query that is designed to find the number of people who went to a hospital more than once.  What I have works, but is there a way to do it without the subquery?

```
SELECT count(*) as counts, hospitals.hospitalname 
    FROM  Patient INNER JOIN
    hospitals ON Patient.hospitalnpi = hospitals.npi
    WHERE     (hospitals.hospitalname = 'X')
    group by patientid, hospitalname
    having count(patient.patientid) >1
    order by count(*) desc
```

This will always return the number of correct rows (30), but not the number 30.  If I remove the `group by patientid` then I get the entire result set returned.

I solved this problem by doing

```
select COUNT(*),hospitalname 
from
(
    SELECT count(*) as counts,hospitals.hospitalname 
        FROM hospitals INNER JOIN
        Patient ON hospitals.npi = Patient.hospitalnpi
        group by patientid, hospitals.hospitalname
        having count(patient.patientid) >1

) t 
group by  t.hospitalname
order by t.hospitalname desc
```

I feel that there has to be a more elegant solution than using subqueries all the time.  How could this be improved?

```
sample data from first query
row #  revisits  
    1  2
    2  2
    3  2
    4  2

same data from second, working query
row#    hosp. name    revisitAggregate
1       x             30 
2       y             15 
3       z             5
```

Simple one-to-many relationship between patient and hospitals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super hacky, but here you are:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by patient.patientid) as Count
FROM  
    Patient 
    INNER JOIN hospitals 
        ON Patient.hospitalnpi = hospitals.npi
WHERE     
    (hospitals.hospitalname = 'X')
GROUP BY 
    patientid, 
    hospitalname
HAVING
    count(patient.patientid) >1
ORDER BY 
    Count desc
```

Comment: @JoseChama Sorry, the userid was left over from my testing.  This is hacky, but it will count all the rows (ROW_NUMBER) and will flip it upside down and return the largest values - ie, the count of how many rows there are.

Comment: @ stefan this returned no results.  I guess the main lesson here is 'no, there's not a better way'

Comment: @wootscootinboogie this should work.  I made a change to remove userID, and swap it with a field that you actually have, could you try that?

Comment: don't know what's up, I still get an empty set returned

Comment: @wootscootinboogie you might want to try it without the where, I had adapted your first query.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie are you running this in the console?  Are you getting any errors back?

Comment: @StefanH, would this work without a subquery in the absence of "hospitals.hospitalname = 'X'" condition, i.e., when patient counts are needed across all hospitals.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct hospitalname, count(*) over (partition by hospitalname) from (
    SELECT hospitalname, count(*) over (partition by   patientid,
    hospitals.hospitalname)   as counter
    FROM hospitals INNER JOIN
    Patient ON hospitals.npi = Patient.hospitalnpi
    WHERE     (hospitals.hospitalname = 'X')
    ) Z
    where counter > 1
```

Comment: I believe that still uses a subquery.

Comment: agreed it takes out one level of sub-queries, which was the most that i thought was possible until I laid eyes on your superhack above